# Is Troy the antagonist in "Fences"?

Tags: character-analysis, august-wilson, fences

Is Troy the antagonist of the play *Fences*? The antagonist is, by definition, the opposer to the protagonist, who is also Troy. However, Troy often acts against his own beliefs (i.e., sending Gabe to the hospital for money).

**Is Troy the main person standing in his own way?**